# Updating variables in the main method?

Tags: java, methods, timer, program-entry-point, updating

I am making a car game in java. The speed of the road is set in the main method, but I need to update the speed (the car going out of bounds and being slowed by grass).

Here is the part were the int that I want to control the speed is changed at.

```
 if(collision[12] > x)        
 {
    roadSpeed = 150;
    System.out.println("outside");
 }
 else
 {
    System.out.println("inside");
    roadSpeed = 100;
 }
```

Here is the main method up to the point that I need to update.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final TestRoad road = new TestRoad();
            road.timer.setDelay(roadSpeed);
```

After the int is changed the main method does not update the timer delay.
I have looked at changelisteners but I don't want any buttons or sliders.

were the int is declared in were it is called

```
public Boolean start = true;
    public int i;
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;
    public static int roadSpeed = 100; //<<<<<<<<<<declared here      
    public int lcolPoint = 0;
    public int rcolPoint = 0;
    public int colSlot = 0;
    public int colOffset = 0;
    public int carY;
    public int[] collision;
    public int[] colBuffer;
    private BufferedImage carImg;
    private Boolean right=false;
    private Boolean left=false;
    private Boolean first=true;




    public TestRoad(){

        this.setFocusable(true);  
        addKeyListener(this);                        //THIS IS ADDING THE KEYLISTENER
        Color colors = new Color(51,102,0);            
        setBackground(colors);


        //uses setPreferredSize instead of setSize because parent component utilizes a layout manager.
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

        collision = new int[500];
        colBuffer = new int[2];

        for(int i=0; i<500; i++){
                collision[i] = 0;   
        }   


        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(25, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                addPoint();
                carMove();    //<<<<< called here
                repaint();
            }
        });
```

carmove -

```
public void carMove()
    {
        if(right==true)
            x+=8;

        if(left==true)
            x-=8;

            colBuffer[0] = collision[1];
            collision[1] = lcolPoint;

             collision[colSlot] = lcolPoint;

           for(int z=2; z<21; z++){
            colBuffer[1] = collision[z];
            collision[z] = colBuffer[0];
            colBuffer[0] = colBuffer[1];
           }    

            if(collision[12] > x)        
            {
                roadSpeed = 100;
                System.out.println("outside");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("inside");
                roadSpeed = 50;
            }   


    }
```

Comment: What in the world is going on with your indentation? Do you really indent the bodies of ifs less than the ifs themselves?

Comment: I normalized the indentation for the rest of the world's reading convenience.

Comment: but I'm damned if I'm going to redo the second blob of code.

Answer (score 1):

Phillip, it would help a whole lot if we could see how you're calling that piece of code.  As it is, we can't see where `roadSpeed` is declared nor have we any clue to its scope.

But, let's say it was something like this

```
class Game {
  private int roadSpeed = 200 ; // just an initial value

  public void getSpeed(int collision, int roadSpeed){
    if(collision[12] > x){
      roadSpeed = 150;
      System.out.println("outside");
    } else {
      System.out.println("inside");
      roadSpeed = 100;
    }
    return;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    // do something that sets collision
    getSpeed(collision, roadSpeed);
    // and on with your code
```

In this code, for example, you *think* you're setting `roadSpeed`, but it's the *inner* `roadSpeed`, not the member variable.

So if this doesn't help, you're going to have to include further hints.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. That makes me suspicious because you should know better.

Comment: well, I just had a more lengthy answer which was, unfortunately, in C.  Now I'm going back and saying it in Java.  As far as being suspicious, don't be such a cynic.

Comment: I added some more code, I hope it helped. Sorry about the poor organization several people are working on this and some of the formatting got messed up when I copy pasted.

Comment: well, it's a start.  Are you sure your actionPerformed function is being called?

Comment: If you are referring to when it is called in the beginning yes. The problem is that when the car goes past the collision point and roadSpeed is changed it does update the road speed. To me it looks like main being run once at the beginning and then never again. Sorry if I'm being difficult, I am still pretty new to this.